# How to execute "OPTIONS" HTTP method request in Java 11 HttpClient

Tags: java, java-http-client

I need to replace Apache http client with java httpClient.

I have a test with an apache client that works well:

```
HttpOptions httpOptions = new HttpOptions(uploadUrl);
try (CloseableHttpResponse responseOld = httpclient.execute(httpOptions)) {
    assertEquals(200, responseOld.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    assertEquals("POST,OPTIONS", responseOld.getFirstHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods").getValue());
}
```

But when I change it to java client, it doesn't work. I use this code:

```
HttpClient javaClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(initUnsecuredSSLContext()).build();

HttpRequest get = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(uploadUrl))
                .method("OPTIONS", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
HttpResponse<String> response = javaClient.send(get, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Test fails to complete when run

java version "17.0.2".

Thanks.

Comment: Your test verifies options returns headers; it doesn't verify it returns a body. The client is ignoring the headers and trying to parse a body.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

Everything was solved with a small change in response

```
HttpRequest get = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(uploadUrl))
                .method("OPTIONS", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();

HttpResponse<Stream<String>> response = javaClient.send(get, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines());

assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
assertEquals("POST,OPTIONS", response.headers().firstValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods").orElseThrow());
```